# Hello, I have a problem trying to port a certain OEM android app

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to port LG system launcher but I can't get it to work due to a certain missing class called "LGSharedPreferences" or something like that. Here is the logcat obtained:

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.lge.launcher3, PID: 9174
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/app/LGSharedPreferences;
    at com.lge.launcher3.util.LGHomeFeature.getPermanentPreferences(LGHomeFeature.java:416)
    at com.lge.launcher3.util.LGHomeFeature.getSwivelHomeStateFromPreferences(LGHomeFeature.java:369)
    at com.lge.launcher3.util.LGHomeFeature.<init>(LGHomeFeature.java:278)
    at com.lge.launcher3.util.LGHomeFeature.init(LGHomeFeature.java:294)
    at com.lge.launcher3.allapps.SwivelAllAppsDBProvider.onCreate(SwivelAllAppsDBProvider.java:28)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2388)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2358)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7248)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6789)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6706)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:238)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1914)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7666)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.app.LGSharedPreferences
    ... 18 more
```

If it helps I tried both installing it as a user app and making a magisk module to install it as a system app (also I bundled with it some libraries I found in the app manifest such as "com.lge.sui" and "com.lge.lgdynamicactionbar" but no luck) and I always get the same error, some help will be highly appreciated

By the way, sorry for my bad English, I'm still learning :)

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that `android.app.LGSharedPreferences` was available at compile time, but is missing at runtime. Given the package name of the class, my guess would be that the class is supposed to be loaded from the OS on LG phones, and you are running the app on a phone that doesn't have that available.

If you have the source code for the app and the library that contains `android.app.LGSharedPreferences`, you should make sure the library containing `LGSharedPreferences` is statically compiled in (probably also change the package name to avoid conflicts on LG phones).

Comment: I see, but unfortunately I don't have the source code of the app nor the library but there's available a LG system dump which I used to extract the libraries I mentioned before. I tried to locate the library that is giving me that problem but no luck, any ideas? By the way, the system dump can be found here: https://dumps.tadiphone.dev/dumps/lge/mh5lm